# Azure api management and Web App

Tags: rest, azure, web, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I have hosted my REST services on API management and consuming those in the Azure Web app service which consists of only HTML pages, javascript files and CSS files.

I would like to know how to restrict accessing the REST endpoints of the API management only from the web app without Azure AD and OAuth setup.

Comment: well, implement some sort of auth, say certificate auth?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm a bit confused at this point, so you have Api and a WebApp? those are 2 different things?

Comment: yes, i have  REST API endpoints on API management and these endpoints should be accessible only from my web application which is hosted on Azure using Web app service.

Comment: should your website be accessible from the web?

Comment: yes, my site should be accessible from the web

Comment: As you mentioned that your web app which consists of only HTML pages, javascript files and CSS files, then how does your web app access the API management endpoints, front-end?

Answer (score 1):

Client side application sources are by design available in clear text to anyone using it. Any user can open developer tools in browser and look at code you've written to make app work. So even if you secure your REST API with some secret and use it in app code to talk to that REST API anyone in the world will be able to take that secret our of the app and call your REST API directly, and you would have no way to distinguish their calls from calls made by your app.

OAuth and AAD would work to a certain extent but even they allow you to authenticate user, not the app. Same user can easily trace calls made by your app to REST API and reproduce them in any other app, and you again would have to way of figuring that out.

I think your best bet is to throttle calls made by a certain user identifying it any way you want (even if by IP address).

Comment: thanks for your quick response. I can't use ip address access restriction in this case. Is there any other way to do it

Comment: No, I don't think there is any way to do it, not just in APIM product, but at all. If you want your app (which is purely client side) to talk to APIM - its fine, if you want to make sure that its only that app that can talk to APIM - i don't see a way to achieve that. Because your app is purely clientside, all it's code and whatever secrets it may have will be visible by end users, thus all those secrets are inherently compromised.

You're either left with authenticating user via OAuth or AAD, or implementing server side for your web app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Certificate authentication from web app to api management. The ssl certficate thumbprint on you web app you can validate in api management policy.